# How to share declaration files from libraries [Typescript]?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have untyped class A from an external library used by my own library where I created class B that extends class A. In order to have typings for class A I make use of declaration files, so I created `lib/typings/external-lib.d.ts` with the following content (it is just an example):

```js
/// <reference types="node" />
declare module 'external-lib' {
    export class A {
        param1: string
        param2: string

        sayHi(): void
        constructor(e: any)
    }

    export default TronWeb
}
```

And here is the code with class A inheriting class B:

```js
import A from 'external-lib'

export class B extends A {
    constructor(options: any[]) {
         super(options)
    }

    doStuff(): void {
         console.log('Hi!')
         console.log('Param1:', this.param1) // it's alright, everything is working here
    }
}

// Now I can access properties and methods from class A creating an instance of class B without typescript issues:
// const b = new B({ option1: true })
// b.sayHi()
```

And `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "target": "es2017",
        "types": ["node", "jest"],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true, 
        "typeRoots": ["lib/typings", "node_modules/@types"]
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
    "include": ["lib/**/*", "typings/**/*", "test/**/*"]
}
```

My library is compiled successfully. However, when I use this library in my project I cannot access properties of class A when I create an instance of class B (I mean, I receive an error from typescript that this property doesn't exist). I want to do something like:

```js
const b = new B({ option1: true })
b.sayHi() // method from class A (typescript throws an error that method doesn't exit)
b.doStuff() // method from class B
console.log(b.param1) // property from class A (typescript throws an error that property doesn't exit)
```

Now I can use only methods from class B but not inherited because typescript doesn't see them. How to resolve this issue? It seems like the project doesn't see declaration files and cannot resolve typings.

Comment: In your library, did you import `lib/typings/external-lib.d.ts` ?
And is it included in field "files" of the library package.json ?

Comment: @shantr where should i do import? It seems I didn't

Comment: Maybe you can try to import it in the file where you are defining the B class

Comment: I may try but the solution seems strange a little bit

Comment: Kinda guessing but when you are working in your library, the file is read (and thus included in the typing) as it is in your workspace.

But when your are in your other project, the file might be never read as it is not imported somewhere

Comment: @shantr now when I do `import A from 'external-lib'` from my project it's working (I mean it sees typings for class A). But typescript still doesn't see inherited props from class A in class B.

Comment: Just to be sure Im understanding correctly, you are using an external dependencies in your own library and then you are using this library in your other project right ?

Instead of adding `import A from 'external-lib'` in your project, did you try adding `import './typings/external-lib.d.ts'` (or whatever relative path) in the file where you are implementing the class B (in your library)

Comment: @shantr yes, and yes i did. And, as a result, now i can add `import A from 'external-lib'` into my project (if this external library is installed in my project) and i can use typings for class A in my prject too. When I navigate my cursor onto this line my IDE shows that typings are exported from my library

Comment: however, still i cannt access properties of parent class A when I create an instance of class B